# Aligning equal signs in the numerator and denominator of a fraction?

Tags: graphics, legending, formatting

I am trying to make a fairly complicated plot that involves `LineLegend`.

As part of the `LineLegend`'s label, I am using `Row[{("test=0.01")/("testing=0.01")}]`.

Is there a straightforward way to align the equal signs?

Comment: `Column[{"test=0.01", "testing=0.01"}, Alignment -> Right, Dividers -> {False, {False, True, False}}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alignment can sometimes take a character to be aligned on. So, in this case (I've changed the text slightly so you can see the effect):

```
Column[{("test=0.01"), ("testing=0.001")}, Alignment -> "="]
```

I've also changed it to column, since you want vertical alignment. To get it to look like a fraction:

```
Column[{("test=0.01"), ("testing=0.001")}, Alignment -> "=", Dividers -> {False, {False, True, False}}]
```

And actually, Column takes alignment as an optional second argument, so this works:

```
Column[{"test=0.01", "testing=0.001"}, "=", Dividers -> {False, {False, True, False}}]
```

Comment: Thanks so much!